# Animating the order of React elements in a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation

I'm trying to animate the vertical position of elements within a list using ReactJS. The elements can be arbitrarily ordered within the list, however they all have unique identifiers.

The elements in the list have a static height and only their vertical position changes.

I'm able to apply `transform: translate(0px, ${index * height}px)` to each element and use `transition: transform 1s ease-in-out` to animate changes to the translation. This results in the elements being rendered in the appropriate order.

However when the elements are re-ordered, only elements moving "up" are animated; elements which end up further below are "snapped" into place automatically.

Ideally I'd want to do this without the help of a library unless the problem is harder than I think it is to solve.

```js
import shuffle from "lodash.shuffle";
import { useState } from "react";

const data = [
  { id: 1, name: "Foo" },
  { id: 2, name: "Bar" },
  { id: 3, name: "Baz" }
];

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(data);
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setItems(shuffle(data));
        }}
      >
        Shuffle
      </button>
      <div style={{ position: "relative" }}>
        {items.map(({ id, name }, index) => (
          <div
            key={id}
            style={{
              position: "absolute",
              border: "1px solid #ddd",
              width: "100%",
              height: 42,
              boxSizing: "border-box",
              transition: "transform 1s ease-in-out",
              transform: `translate(${0}px, ${index * 42}px)`
            }}
          >
            {name}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Sorry... not quite an answer, but what if you will remove `key` property? We have it in React to optimize rendering of lists. Maybe elements that change their place up are considered "changed" and ones which you observe as just popping into their own place - are considered not changed. Thus to achieve your specific goal you (if this will work as I'm not sure), you need to achieve disablement of this optimization.

Comment: When the key is removed, no animations occur at all.